# Can Virtual DOM be crawled by any of the website like crawling the shadow DOM?

Tags: reactjs, web, dom, web-crawler, virtual-dom

I read various articles about virtual DOM and Shadow DOM, their usage, reasons to opt for any one of them, etc.

But I recently came across a research paper mentioning that they were not able to crawl the Shadow DOM elements for some reason using their website crawlers.

However I find some Shadow DOM crawlers on the internet like https://www.npmjs.com/package/shadow-dom-crawler - But the owner strictly mentions not to use this crawler for updating any fields on the web page (Or that is what I understood from it).

So I was wondering if there are any useful crawlers to crawl virtual DOM?
Or since there is no much difference between the actual DOM and the virtual DOM, the process of developing and working on both the corresponding crawlers should be the same?

Comment: A "virtual DOM" is a concept only related to React, and it's not related to the "Shadow DOM," which is part of the DOM standard.

Comment: So say if a web page is built using react and I am trying to crawl it. Will I be able to perform successful crawling of all the user input fields from it?

Comment: React outputs vanilla DOM elements. The shadow DOM relates to the Web Components open standard. https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html

Comment: Yeah so apart from the difference between these two, when I crawl the DOM of a webpage built using react, will the crawler be able to crawl virtual DOM elements too?

Comment: The "Virtual DOM" is simply objects in memory that react holds. It's "react elements" - just objects/data. React outputs vanilla HTML / vanilla DOM elements from this "virtual DOM" representation. You can't "crawl" the virtual DOM because it's not actually in the DOM. The virtual DOM is used to track which parts of the real DOM to update. Any updates React makes ends up as real DOM elements. The "Virtual DOM" is just a name of the data react holds.